# How does `mapping(address => uint) public balances` get balances?

Tags: mapping

I noticed that `balances` as a mapping

```
mapping(address => uint) public balances;
```

and acts as a dictionary where addresses are mapped to balances.(address -> balance). For a typical dictionary to do so, we need to first provide/initialise the dictionary with some entries of `address -> balance` pair(s). But in solidity, its still able to fetch balances.

How is this accomplished ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the token contract is deployed, the mapping is empty - there is no data.

Often, during the deployment, some tokens are minted (created out of thin air) and assigned to the deployer's address. So an entry is added which maps the deployer's `address` to a `uint` balance. Basically it says "this address has this balance". Whenever the balance of any address is modified, the same mapping's `uint` value (for the given `address`) is modified.

When someone queries the balance for that address, the same mapping is used to retrieve the balance for the given address.

Answer (score 0):

Well `_transfer` and `_mint` function (the 2 only way to get tokens) update the users balances